# Seaborn boxplots shifted incorrectly along x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({})
df[soi_name]=soi
df[outcome_name]=outcome
soi,outcome = utils.format_cols(soi, outcome,'continuous',agg_method)
sns.factorplot(data=df, x=outcome_name,y=soi_name,hue=outcome_name,kind='box')
plt.savefig(ofilepath)
```

[image]

So the code snippet used to generate this boxplot is just above.  outcome is a binary float type pandas series.  soi is a float type pandas series.  This x-axis shift occurs for boxplots and violinplots.  When I generate factor plots with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df[soi_name]=soi
df[outcome_name]=outcome
sns.factorplot(data=df, x=outcome_name,y=soi_name,hue=outcome_name)
plt.savefig(ofilepath)
```

...
[image]

I get my desired outputs.  Any ideas with why the shift for the box plots might be happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two different `hue`s, such that the first is plotted left of the position and the second is plotted right of the position. This is usually desired, see e.g. this plot from [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time",
                  data=tips, linewidth=2.5)

plt.show()
```

Here, you wouldn't want to have the blue and orange boxplots overlapping, would you?

But you can, if you want. Use the `dodge=False` argument for that purpose.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time",
                  dodge=False, data=tips, linewidth=2.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!!